# Compilation Error with make file

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile, g++

I've developed a C++ project using eclipse. When I launch the `Run` command from within the IDE everything will work fine and programs exits with success.
This is the build output obtained with Eclipse's make file:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project IVPM ****

make all 
Building file: ../IVPM.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/include/c++/4.5.2 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -MMD -MP -MF"IVPM.d" -MT"IVPM.d" -o "IVPM.o" "../IVPM.cpp"
Finished building: ../IVPM.cpp

Building file: ../TemplateMatx3.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/include/c++/4.5.2 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -MMD -MP -MF"TemplateMatx3.d" -MT"TemplateMatx3.d" -o "TemplateMatx3.o" "../TemplateMatx3.cpp"
Finished building: ../TemplateMatx3.cpp

Building file: ../main.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/include/c++/4.5.2 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"
Finished building: ../main.cpp

Building target: IVPM
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o "IVPM"  ./IVPM.o ./Matx3.o ./TemplateMatx3.o ./main.o   -lopencv_core -lpng -lopencv_highgui
Finished building target: IVPM

**** Build Finished ****
```

I was now trying to write a makefile on my own but am not able to compile with success.  Here is what I've done so far:

```
all:main

main:IVPM.o TemplateMatx3.o
    g++ IVPM.o TemplateMatx3.o -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lpng -lopencv_highgui -o main -c main.cpp

TemplateMatx3.o:TemplateMatx3.cpp
    g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include/opencv2 -I/usr/include/c++/4.5.2 -O0 -g3 -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -c TemplateMatx3.cpp

IVPM.o:IVPM.cpp
    g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include/opencv2 -I/usr/include/c++/4.5.2 -O0 -g3 -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -c IVPM.cpp

clean:
    rm -rf *o main
```

But compiling on a shell with the `make` command will result in the following errors:

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include/opencv2 -I/usr/include/c++/4.5.2 -O0 -g3 -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -c IVPM.cpp
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include/opencv2 -I/usr/include/c++/4.5.2 -O0 -g3 -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -c TemplateMatx3.cpp
g++ IVPM.o TemplateMatx3.o -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lpng -lopencv_highgui -o main -c main.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.5/type_traits:35:0,
                 from IVPM.h:39,
                 from main.cpp:8:
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/c++0x_warning.h:31:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.
In file included from main.cpp:9:0:
IVPM.cpp: In member function ‘void IVPM<Matx3DataType>::loadImagesFromFileAndProcessAndSave(const std::string&, const std::string&, const std::string&, IVPM<Matx3DataType>::loadImageType, IVPM<Matx3DataType>::saveImageFormat, IVPM<Matx3DataType>::imageOperationType, float, float, IVPM<Matx3DataType>::interpolationType)’:
IVPM.cpp:140:39: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>::open(const std::string&, const std::ios_base::openmode&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/fstream:526:7: note: candidate is: void std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]
IVPM.cpp: In member function ‘std::vector<TemplateMatx3<Matx3DataType>*>* IVPM<Matx3DataType>::loadImagesFromFileAndProcessAndReturn(const std::string&, const std::string&, IVPM<Matx3DataType>::loadImageType, IVPM<Matx3DataType>::imageOperationType, float, float, IVPM<Matx3DataType>::interpolationType)’:
IVPM.cpp:208:39: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>::open(const std::string&, const std::ios_base::openmode&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/fstream:526:7: note: candidate is: void std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]
IVPM.cpp: In member function ‘void IVPM<Matx3DataType>::convertMatx3VectorAndProcessAndSave(std::vector<TemplateMatx3<Matx3DataType>*>*, const std::string&, IVPM<Matx3DataType>::saveImageFormat, IVPM<Matx3DataType>::imageOperationType, float, float, IVPM<Matx3DataType>::interpolationType)’:
IVPM.cpp:555:58: error: there are no arguments to ‘to_string’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘to_string’ must be available
IVPM.cpp:555:58: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
IVPM.cpp: In member function ‘void IVPM<Matx3DataType>::loadMatx3FromFileAndProcessAndSave(const std::string&, const std::string&, IVPM<Matx3DataType>::matx3FileType, const std::string&, IVPM<Matx3DataType>::saveImageFormat, IVPM<Matx3DataType>::imageOperationType, float, float, IVPM<Matx3DataType>::interpolationType)’:
IVPM.cpp:704:38: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>::open(const std::string&, const std::ios_base::openmode&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/fstream:526:7: note: candidate is: void std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]
IVPM.cpp: In member function ‘std::vector<TemplateMatx3<Matx3DataType>*>* IVPM<Matx3DataType>::loadMatx3FromFileAndProcessAndReturn(const std::string&, const std::string&, IVPM<Matx3DataType>::matx3FileType, IVPM<Matx3DataType>::imageOperationType, float, float, IVPM<Matx3DataType>::interpolationType)’:
IVPM.cpp:740:38: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>::open(const std::string&, const std::ios_base::openmode&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/fstream:526:7: note: candidate is: void std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]
IVPM.cpp: In member function ‘void IVPM<Matx3DataType>::loadVideoAndProcessAndSave(const std::string&, const std::string&, IVPM<Matx3DataType>::saveImageFormat, float, float, float, bool, IVPM<Matx3DataType>::imageOperationType, float, float, IVPM<Matx3DataType>::interpolationType) [with Matx3DataType = double, std::string = std::basic_string<char>]’:
main.cpp:84:2:   instantiated from here
IVPM.cpp:315:118: error: ‘to_string’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Apparently the compiler is not able to find matching functions of the std library. But I've included the std library in my compiling options, so why is the compiler complaining? And what is the correct procedure to follow?

Comment: I believe the very first error message answers your question

Comment: Are you including `IVPM.cpp` from `main.cpp`?

Comment: @DavidBrown - but I've included the `-std=c++0x` command

Comment: @Matteo - you haven't included it in the compilation line for `main`.

Comment: @OmriBarel - Yes, main includes `IVPM.cpp`

Comment: But you're also compiling `IVPM.cpp` separately (to `IVPM.o`). Why would you also include it in `main.cpp`?

Comment: @DavidBrown - I c, but main doesn't use any C++ class of the standard library, it just calls methods of the IVPM class. Should I still include the option?

Comment: @Matteo: As the error message says, `main.cpp` includes `IVMP.h`, which includes C++11 headers; so it does indeed have to be compiled as C++11, unless you can remove that dependency.

Comment: @OmriBarel - I use the main class to call only some methods of the IVPM class (the ones I need at a certain point). Main is just for checking that the implementation is done correctly. Is there a better way of doing so?thanks for your help

Comment: @MikeSeymour - after adding the option `-std=c++0x` and compiling again the errors are gone, but I get this output `g++: IVPM.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: TemplateMatx3.o: linker input file unused because linking not done` and no executable file is returned. Can you please help me?

Comment: @Matteo: Remove `-c` from the rule for `main` - that tells it to just compile and not link. Alternatively, have two rules - one to compile `main.o` from `main.cpp`, and another to link all the objects separately from compilation.

Comment: @MikeSeymour - it worked!thks a lot ;D